# Sceneform and geolocation

Tags: arcore, sceneform

Using ARCore and Sceneform Im am trying to add a portrait on a vertical surface (which is a wall) i am currently using ViewRenderer to do that from the Sceneform Library.. all works perfectly but im now facing 2 problems:

First problem was that ViewRenderer will render an Android view in 3D so i had to rotate the Node on its right vector 90 degrees so it flats out on the wall.. that works but now my second problem is that i need the portrait to always be straight up with earth's gravity.

How would it be possible to achieve that ?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: I am also going through the same problem. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research i found that the best solution right now [here](https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location).

But that solution would be perfect if you apply a bit of normalisation of the sensor data so it doesn't jump around often.

Comment: @N Jay have you tried the same with GeoSpatial Api?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call Pose.extractTranslation() (https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose.html#extractTranslation()) when creating the Anchor for your object. This removes the rotation part from Pose that is added when ARCore handles the touch event.
With https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Session#createAnchor(com.google.ar.core.Pose) you can create a new Anchor from that pose.

If you have an ArFragment it would look like this:

```
arFragment?.setOnTapArPlaneListener { hitResult, plane, motionEvent ->
        val arSession = arFragment.arSceneView.session
        val hitPose = hitResult.hitPose
        val poseWithoutRotation = hitPose.extractTranslation()
        val anchor = arSession.createAnchor(poseWithoutRotation)
        val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
        ...
```

Comment: How to create a new Anchor with extractTranslation ?

Comment: Do you mind actually adding some code to explain the removing of rotation part ?